# Why won't this display the html?

Tags: php, html

Why won't this work? It should only display the html if the $a Boolean is true.
Am I displaying html conditionally with php correctly?
I really don't know why it won't work. I would really appreciate any help that could be given to me. :)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>

<?php
 $a = False;
 if($a == True){
 <head>
    <title>No Sidebar - Escape Velocity by HTML5 UP</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="assets/js/ie/html5shiv.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main.css" />
    <!--[if lte IE 8]><link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/ie8.css" /><![endif]-->
</head>
<body class="no-sidebar">
    <div id="page-wrapper">

        <!-- Header -->
            <div id="header-wrapper" class="wrapper">
                <div id="header">

                    <!-- Logo -->
                        <div id="logo">
                            <h1><a href="index.html">Escape Velocity</a></h1>
                            <p>A free responsive site template by HTML5 UP</p>
                        </div>

                    <!-- Nav -->
                        <nav id="nav">
                            <ul>
                                <li class="current"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Dropdown</a>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Magna veroeros</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Etiam nisl</a></li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">Sed consequat</a>
                                            <ul>
                                                <li><a href="#">Lorem dolor</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#">Amet consequat</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#">Magna phasellus</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#">Etiam nisl</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#">Sed feugiat</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Nisl tempus</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="left-sidebar.html">Left Sidebar</a></li>
                                <li><a href="right-sidebar.html">Right Sidebar</a></li>
                                <li><a href="no-sidebar.html">No Sidebar</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </nav>

                </div>
            </div>

        <!-- Main -->
            <div class="wrapper style2">
                <div class="title">No Sidebar</div>
                <div id="main" class="container">

                    <!-- Content -->
                        <div id="content">
                            <article class="box post">
                                <header class="style1">
                                    <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet magna egestas<br class="mobile-hide" />
                                    morbi bibendum sed malesuada</h2>
                                    <p>Tempus feugiat veroeros sed nullam dolore</p>
                                </header>
                                <a href="#" class="image featured">
                                    <img src="images/pic01.jpg" alt="" />
                                </a>
                                <p>Fringilla nisl. Donec accumsan interdum nisi, quis tincidunt felis sagittis eget.
                                odio eleifend. Duis commodo fringilla commodo. Aliquam erat volutpat. Vestibulum
                                facilisis leo magna. Cras sit amet urna eros, id egestas urna. Quisque aliquam
                                tempus euismod. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus.</p>
                                <p>Phasellus nisl nisl, varius id porttitor sed, pellentesque ac orci. Pellentesque
                                habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Morbi
                                bibendum justo sed mauris vehicula malesuada aliquam elit imperdiet. Aliquam eu nibh
                                lorem, eget gravida mi. Duis odio diam, luctus et vulputate vitae, vehicula ac dolor.
                                Pellentesque at urna eget tellus lobortis ultrices sed non erat. Donec eget erat non
                                magna volutpat malesuada quis eget eros. Nullam sodales cursus sapien, id consequat
                                leo suscipit ut. Praesent id turpis vitae turpis pretium ultricies. Vestibulum sit
                                amet risus elit.</p>
                                <p>Donec consectetur vestibulum dolor et pulvinar. Etiam vel felis enim, at viverra
                                ligula. Ut porttitor sagittis lorem, quis eleifend nisi ornare vel. Praesent nec orci
                                eget quam rutrum bibendum. Proin pellentesque diam non ligula commodo tempor. Vivamus
                                eget urna nibh. Curabitur non fringilla nisl. Donec accumsan interdum nisi, quis
                                tincidunt felis sagittis eget. Donec elementum ligula dignissim sem pulvinar non semper
                                odio eleifend. Duis commodo fringilla commodo. Aliquam erat volutpat. Vestibulum
                                facilisis leo magna. Cras sit amet urna eros, id egestas urna. Quisque aliquam
                                tempus euismod. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices
                                posuere cubilia.</p>
                                <p>Phasellus nisl nisl, varius id porttitor sed, pellentesque ac orci. Pellentesque
                                habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Morbi
                                bibendum justo sed mauris vehicula malesuada aliquam elit imperdiet. Aliquam eu nibh
                                lorem, eget gravida mi. Duis odio diam, luctus et vulputate vitae, vehicula ac dolor.
                                Pellentesque at urna eget tellus lobortis ultrices sed non erat. Donec eget erat non
                                magna volutpat malesuada quis eget eros. Nullam sodales cursus sapien, id consequat
                                leo suscipit ut. Praesent id turpis vitae turpis pretium ultricies. Vestibulum sit
                                amet risus elit.</p>
                            </article>
                            <div class="row 150%">
                                <div class="4u 12u(mobile)">
                                    <section class="box">
                                        <header>
                                            <h2>Magna pulvinar tempus</h2>
                                        </header>
                                        <a href="#" class="image featured"><img src="images/pic05.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                                        <p>Rutrum bibendum. Proin pellentesque diam non ligula commodo tempor. Vivamus
                                        eget urna nibh. Curabitur non fringilla nisl. Donec accumsan interdum nisi, quis
                                        tempus.</p>
                                        <a href="#" class="button style1">More</a>
                                    </section>
                                </div>
                                <div class="4u 12u(mobile)">
                                    <section class="box">
                                        <header>
                                            <h2>Magna pulvinar tempus</h2>
                                        </header>
                                        <a href="#" class="image featured"><img src="images/pic06.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                                        <p>Rutrum bibendum. Proin pellentesque diam non ligula commodo tempor. Vivamus
                                        eget urna nibh. Curabitur non fringilla nisl. Donec accumsan interdum nisi, quis
                                        tempus.</p>
                                        <a href="#" class="button style1">More</a>
                                    </section>
                                </div>
                                <div class="4u 12u(mobile)">
                                    <section class="box">
                                        <header>
                                            <h2>Magna pulvinar tempus</h2>
                                        </header>
                                        <a href="#" class="image featured"><img src="images/pic07.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                                        <p>Rutrum bibendum. Proin pellentesque diam non ligula commodo tempor. Vivamus
                                        eget urna nibh. Curabitur non fringilla nisl. Donec accumsan interdum nisi, quis
                                        tempus.</p>
                                        <a href="#" class="button style1">More</a>
                                    </section>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                </div>
            </div>

        <!-- Highlights -->
            <div class="wrapper style3">
                <div class="title">The Endorsements</div>
                <div id="highlights" class="container">
                    <div class="row 150%">
                        <div class="4u 12u(mobile)">
                            <section class="highlight">
                                <a href="#" class="image featured"><img src="images/pic02.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                                <h3><a href="#">Aliquam diam consequat</a></h3>
                                <p>Eget mattis at, laoreet vel amet sed velit aliquam diam ante, dolor aliquet sit amet vulputate mattis amet laoreet lorem.</p>
                                <ul class="actions">
                                    <li><a href="#" class="button style1">Learn More</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </section>
                        </div>
                        <div class="4u 12u(mobile)">
                            <section class="highlight">
                                <a href="#" class="image featured"><img src="images/pic03.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                                <h3><a href="#">Nisl adipiscing sed lorem</a></h3>
                                <p>Eget mattis at, laoreet vel amet sed velit aliquam diam ante, dolor aliquet sit amet vulputate mattis amet laoreet lorem.</p>
                                <ul class="actions">
                                    <li><a href="#" class="button style1">Learn More</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </section>
                        </div>
                        <div class="4u 12u(mobile)">
                            <section class="highlight">
                                <a href="#" class="image featured"><img src="images/pic04.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                                <h3><a href="#">Mattis tempus lorem</a></h3>
                                <p>Eget mattis at, laoreet vel amet sed velit aliquam diam ante, dolor aliquet sit amet vulputate mattis amet laoreet lorem.</p>
                                <ul class="actions">
                                    <li><a href="#" class="button style1">Learn More</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </section>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        <!-- Footer -->
            <div id="footer-wrapper" class="wrapper">
                <div class="title">The Rest Of It</div>
                <div id="footer" class="container">
                    <header class="style1">
                        <h2>Ipsum sapien elementum portitor?</h2>
                        <p>
                            Sed turpis tortor, tincidunt sed ornare in metus porttitor mollis nunc in aliquet.<br />
                            Nam pharetra laoreet imperdiet volutpat etiam consequat feugiat.
                        </p>
                    </header>
                    <hr />
                    <div class="row 150%">
                        <div class="6u 12u(mobile)">

                            <!-- Contact Form -->
                                <section>
                                    <form method="post" action="#">
                                        <div class="row 50%">
                                            <div class="6u 12u(mobile)">
                                                <input type="text" name="name" id="contact-name" placeholder="Name" />
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="6u 12u(mobile)">
                                                <input type="text" name="email" id="contact-email" placeholder="Email" />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="row 50%">
                                            <div class="12u">
                                                <textarea name="message" id="contact-message" placeholder="Message" rows="4"></textarea>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="12u">
                                                <ul class="actions">
                                                    <li><input type="submit" class="style1" value="Send" /></li>
                                                    <li><input type="reset" class="style2" value="Reset" /></li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
                                </section>

                        </div>
                        <div class="6u 12u(mobile)">

                            <!-- Contact -->
                                <section class="feature-list small">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="6u 12u(mobile)">
                                            <section>
                                                <h3 class="icon fa-home">Mailing Address</h3>
                                                <p>
                                                    Untitled Corporation<br />
                                                    1234 Somewhere Rd #987<br />
                                                    Nashville, TN 00000-0000
                                                </p>
                                            </section>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="6u 12u(mobile)">
                                            <section>
                                                <h3 class="icon fa-comment">Social</h3>
                                                <p>
                                                    <a href="#">@untitled-corp</a><br />
                                                    <a href="#">linkedin.com/untitled</a><br />
                                                    <a href="#">facebook.com/untitled</a>
                                                </p>
                                            </section>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="6u 12u(mobile)">
                                            <section>
                                                <h3 class="icon fa-envelope">Email</h3>
                                                <p>
                                                    <a href="#">info@untitled.tld</a>
                                                </p>
                                            </section>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="6u 12u(mobile)">
                                            <section>
                                                <h3 class="icon fa-phone">Phone</h3>
                                                <p>
                                                    (000) 555-0000
                                                </p>
                                            </section>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </section>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <hr />
                </div>
                <div id="copyright">
                    <ul>
                        <li>&copy; Untitled.</li><li>Design: <a href="http://html5up.net">HTML5 UP</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>

    </div>

    <!-- Scripts -->

        <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/jquery.dropotron.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/skel.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/skel-viewport.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/util.js"></script>
        <!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="assets/js/ie/respond.min.js"></script><![endif]-->
        <script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>

</body>
    } ?>



    </html>
```

Comment: question is, where is `$a` assigned in order to become TRUE? and how are you accessing this file, via the www or local and "how" if local? as `http://localhost` or as `file:///`? Those are two different animals altogether.

Comment: I didn't assign $a to be TRUE because I wanted to test if the php code would conditionally display the HTML within the if loop and I'm accessing it locally.

Comment: Most important part of @Fred-ii- question there is **Are you doubleclicking on the filename in windows explorer** or entering a url manually into the browser address bar??

Comment: easiest method would be to simply include a file rather than doing what you're doing now. Just way too many things can go wrong.

Comment: This file:///C:/Users/dominic.hipsher/Desktop/devproject/admin/index.php

Comment: well there you go ^^^^^^^^^ that's why. I knew it. Use `http://localhost/file.php` as I already stated above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you need to turn PHP off when you are outputting raw HTML so at the top change to this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>

<?php
 $a = False;
 if($a == True){
?>                         <-- new line
<head>
```

And at the bottom change to this

```
</body>
<?php } ?>                  <-- changed line
```

Comment: It still displays the html though and it won't display it correctly when doing that. I know separating your html and php is good practice but this doesn't seem to solve the problem.

Comment: Hmmm strange. I assume the file extension on this script is `.php` is that correct?

Comment: Yes I did, It should only display the html if $a is true and it should display it correctly but it does neither with your modification.

Comment: Can you make absolutely sure that the script file name ends with a `.php` extension. Especially if you are on Windows and you are using notepad as an editor.

Comment: It defiantly is a .php file no question about that.

Comment: Did you add my suggested changes? without the labels!

Comment: Yes I did. I'm rather clueless why this won't conditionally display the html properly and why it won't display it correctly either.

Comment: So you are saying it always paints a page in your browser even though `$a` is set to `false`

Comment: Yes that is what I am saying.

Comment: **You have to use the browser to launch PHP scripts i.e. from the browser address bar manually**, as it is Apache that spots the `<?php` tags and then passes to script to PHP for interpretation and Execution. If you click the file in EXPLORER you are not using Apache and therefore the PHP never gets executed.

Comment: Do you have a web server and PHP installed?

Comment: Thanks for the answer RiggsFolly. I got it working by uploading it to my free test server here and setting the $a boolean to True to see if it displays correctly which it doesn't. http://dominiccstn.site88.net/admin/index.php

Comment: Have a think about installing a localserver. WAMPServer or XAMPP if you are a windows user. You cannot test a PHP web page code locally without one

Comment: If you goto http://dominiccstn.site88.net/admin/index.php the html code isn't being display correctly and it's unacceptable for what I'm doing for it to be that way. :/

Comment: Thats got nothing to do with the question you asked. You will have to look at your HTML to work that problem out!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you're trying to parse the HTML as PHP. You have to either close the PHP-tag, or echo it. It'd probably be better to just close the PHP-tag, as such:

```
if($a == True){
    ?>
    <head>
    <!--- More HTML here --->
```

and to open it before the closing-bracket of your if-statement:

```
    <!--- HTML coming in here... --->
    </body>
<?php } ?>
```